# JNDI over HTTP on JBoss 4.2.3GA

Tags: http, jboss, jndi

I've got a remote server on eapps.com that I'm using as my "production" server. I have my own computer at home that I'm using as my "development" server. I'm trying to use JNDI over HTTP to do some batch processing. The following works at home, but not on the eapps machine.

I'm connecting to some EJBs (stateless session), and have my jndi.properties set to this:

(this is for the eapps machine)

```
java.naming.factory.initial=org.jboss.naming.HttpNamingContextFactory
java.naming.provider.url=http://my.prodhost.com:8080/invoker/JNDIFactory
java.naming.factory.url.pkgs=org.jboss.naming.client:org.jnp.interfaces
# timeout is in milliseconds
jnp.timeout=15000
jnp.sotimeout=15000
jnp.maxRetries=3
```

(this is for my machine at home)

```
java.naming.factory.initial=org.jboss.naming.HttpNamingContextFactory
java.naming.provider.url=http://localhost:8080/invoker/JNDIFactory
java.naming.factory.url.pkgs=org.jnp.interfaces
java.naming.factory.url.pkgs=org.jboss.naming.client
# timeout is in milliseconds
jnp.timeout=15000
jnp.sotimeout=15000
jnp.maxRetries=3
```

As I said, it works at home, but when I try it remotely, I get:

```
Can not get connection to server. Problem establishing socket connection for InvokerLocator [socket://my.prodhost.com:4446//?dataType=invocation&enableTcpNoDelay=true&marshaller=org.jboss.invocation.unified.marshall.InvocationMarshaller&socketTimeout=600000&unmarshaller=org.jboss.invocation.unified.marshall.InvocationUnMarshaller]
...
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out: connect
```

Am I doing something wrong here, or is it possibly a firewall issue? To the best of my knowledge, port 4446 is not blocked.

Comment: The difference is not intention. I'll make them the same and try again.

Only the eapps machine is Unix. When I tried "netstat -a | grep 4446", it returned nothing. The eapps documentation suggested that I try "iptables -A INPUT -j ACCEPT -p tcp --dport [port number]", but that didn't seem to work. I'm not a Unix person; I know the bare minimum about using it.

Comment: Even thought the first question has been answered, I'm going to add to this with the subsequent problems that I find and hopefully their solutions. After applying the HTTP UnifiedInvoker fix, I found that my remote SLSB would not load. I found this error in the JBoss log file:
[org.jboss.system.ServiceController] Problem creating service jboss.remoting:service=Connector,transport=socket
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/coyote/Adapter

Comment: Here's a very interesting link:
http://blog.saddey.net/2007/05/19/jboss-420ga-unified-invoker-jboss-remoting-not-too-much-excitement-for-me-yet/
and
https://jira.jboss.org/jira/browse/JBAS-2766

Answer (score 1):

Are the differences in the `jndi.properties` intentional (at the `java.naming.factory.url.pkgs` property level)?

Also, can you run a `netstat -a | grep 4446` on both machines and update the question with the output?

**Update:** If the `netstat` command didn't return anything for port 4446 (JBoss was running, right?), then the JBoss Remoting `Connector` for the [UnifiedInvoker](http://docs.jboss.org/jbossas/unified_invoker/UnifiedInvoker_guide.html) service is very likely not listening on your eApps host, hence the connection timeout. Maybe this service has been disabled by eApps, you should contact the [support](https://support.eapps.com/) and discuss this with them.

Just in case, a sample `Connector` configuration can be found in the `jboss-service.xml` under the server node's `conf` directory. Maybe compare the remote one (if you have access to it) with your local file to confirm this (but if it's disable, there must be a reason, discuss it with the support).

And by the way, this is what I get when I run the `netstat` command with JBoss 4.2.3.GA started on my GNU/Linux machine (default configuration):

```
$ netstat -a | grep 4446
tcp        0      0 localhost:4446          *:*                     LISTEN
```

Comment: Sorry that I haven't been able to respond. I'm on a business trip and will be back this weekend. Will look at it then.

Comment: That looks like it did it. The trick was "To change the UnifiedInvoker to use HTTP transport instead of the socket one"